# jquery mouseenter triggered on ios Safari and other touch devices. How to stop it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, responsive-design, touch

I have the following code on my site:

```
    /* Show arrows when card is hovered */
    $('BODY').on('mouseenter', '.card', function (event) {
        $(this).addClass('is-hovered');
    });

    $('BODY').on('mouseleave', '.card', function (event) {
        $(this).removeClass('is-hovered');
    });
```

The idea is than on devices with a mouse, each card will show little arrows when the mouse hovers over them. On touch devices these arrows should never appear because the card can be swiped instead.

The problem is that the jQuery mouseenter event is being triggered on iOS Safari when you press on a card. Not always, but especially when pressing an image inside the card. It seems fairly random in nature though. Can I disable Safari from registering the hover at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a library that detects touch devices , for example modernizr adds the class no-touch to the html tag or via modernizr js using

`if (Modernizr.touch) { 
  //is touch 
}else{ 
  //is screen 
}`

See here about the js part http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/detect-touch-device-modernizr/

Comment: Would the arrows not get shown on a windows 8 computer than has touch AND mouse?

Comment: It will probably report the device as touch but then you could just use css3 media queries to allow the hovering for devices that have a big resolution even if they are touch .

Comment: Thanks, that may be the closest I can get for now, I will mark it as correct if nobody chips in with a 100% robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `Virtual Mouse (vmouse) Bindings` from `jQuery Mobile`, something like this:

```
    $('BODY').on('vmouseover', '.card', function (event) {
        $(this).addClass('is-hovered');
    });

    $('BODY').on('vmouseout', '.card', function (event) {
        $(this).removeClass('is-hovered');
    });
```

About these events:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/vmouseover/

http://api.jquerymobile.com/vmouseout/